# Attribute query OpenLayers server

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, mapserver, html

As part of the MapServer polygons (district boundaries) are shown on the OpenLayers map. The script is in JavaScript. The polygons contain attributes. 
Currently, a second window opens with the corresponding attributes when a polygon is selected.
What function must be used for the attributes to appear in the same window (in a selected area)?

This is my current query.

```
         var abfrage = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({

               protocol: OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                   url: GeoDataURL,
                   featureType: "VZKO",
                    featurePrefix: "ms",
                    version: "1.0.0",
                    srsName: "EPSG:31467",
                    geometryName: "msGeometry",

                   filterType: OpenLayers.Filter.Spatial.BBOX
               }),
               box: true,
               multipleKey: "shiftKey"

           });
           abfrage.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
               //alert(" in fselected");
               //layerSelect.addFeatures([e.feature]);
               var feats = e.feature;
                initMapMode();
                DossierVZ(feats);

                /*var Msg = "<hr>";
                var NL  = "<br>";

                for(var key in feats.attributes)
                     Msg += key + ":" + feats.attributes[key] + NL;
                Msg += "geometry:" + feats.geometry + NL;
                document.getElementById('Auswertung').innerHTML += Msg;*/
           });
```

Comment: Take a look at this OpenLayers example http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/light-basic.html

Comment: what does  DossierVZ(feats); do?

Comment: i think you are looking for vector-features-with-text http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.13.1/examples/vector-features-with-text.html